# ER Modelling tool for schema generation in SAP HANA

Tags: sql, model, entity-relationship, hana

Is there any good ER Modelling tool available for SAP HANA , which accomplishes the following :

- Creation of ER Diagrams
- Generating HANA specific SQL Scripts
- Connecting to HANA DB Instance
- Generating all schema objects modelled

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web IDE for SAP HANA that was delivered with XS Advanced in SAP HANA 2.0 SP01 sounds like what you are looking for as it has a graphical editor to create and link database entities (this is what it looks like):

[Core Data Services graphical editor Web IDE for SAP HANA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4v5X.png)

With XS Advanced, the model is container-based and schema-less.

Here are a couple of links if you would like to try it out:

- Getting started with XS Advanced (in the HDI step, right click on any of the .hdbcds files and you will have the option to open it in the graphical editor):  https://www.sap.com/developer/groups/hana-xsa-get-started.html
- If you need to integrate a database schema from XS Classic or, for example, an ERP replicated schema, you can search for xsa-create-user-provided-anonymous-service in the same site

As for "HANA-specific SQL scripts", it depends on what you are trying to do. If you want to access data in an optimized way and perform calculations, you can use Calculation Views, which are built graphically and the DB will do the equivalent to SQL under the hood. There are some tutorials in the developer[dot]sap[dot]com website, under the Developer->tutorial menu.

If you do not have a HANA instance to try this and/or EA designer you can download your own HANA instance for free:

- Download SAP HANA, express edition (you will need the XS Advanced tooling that includes the Web IDE for SAP HANA): sap[dot]com/developer/topics/sap-hana-express.html
- If your computer does not have enough resources to comfortably host your HANA instance, there's a blog on how to install it in a cloud platform using a free operating system, search for hana-express-edition-on-google-cloud-platform-and-ubuntu  (sorry, I cannot post any more links).

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

There are two tools from SAP:
SAP (Sybase) Powerdesigner, also supporting different other DBs, e.g. for reverse engineering. With Powerdesigner you can model conceptual, logical, physical Data models and also generate a HANA DB schema in different ways, e.g. by generating scripts containing "create..." statements or CDS files.
Then there is the Enterprise Architecture Designer which can be installed as addon in HANA XS advanced starting with HANA 2.0. This tool is quite new and I have not worked with it yet.
There are probably also tools from other vendors.